# Counting Values In An Array

Tags: php, arrays, count

Okay, this small problem is driving me insane.

This is the print_r output of $strap_materials:

```
Array(
    [0] => steel
    [1] => leather
    [2] => polyester
    [3] => leather
    [4] => steel 
)
```

I want to count how many times each value exists and put each sum in an array within an array, just like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        "name"  => steel
        "count" => 2
    )
    [1] => Array(
        "name"  => leather
        "count" => 2
    )
    [0] => Array(
        "name"  => polyester
        "count" => 1
    )
)
```

My intention is to use the newly created array like this:

```
foreach($straps as $strap) {
    echo "Name: " . $strap->name;
    echo "Count: " . $strap->count;
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Its very easy in Ruby.

Comment: RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @beck03076 we are talking about php not Ruby!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$counts = array_count_values($strap_materials);

foreach ($counts as $name => $count) {
    ...
}
```